# How to get frequencies then add it as a variable in an array?

Tags: r

Let's say I have an array of this format

```
X  Y  Z
A  1  0
A  2  1
B  1  1
B  2  1
B  1  0
```

I want to find the frequency of X and the frequency of Y given X, then add them to the array

```
X  Y  Z  F(x)  F(Y|X)
A  1  0  2     1
A  2  1  2     1
B  1  1  3     2
B  2  1  3     1
B  1  0  3     2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` way:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[,nx:=.N,by=X][,nxy:=.N,by=list(X,Y)]
```

That last step created the two columns:

```
DT
#    X Y Z nx nxy
# 1: A 1 0  2   1
# 2: A 2 1  2   1
# 3: B 1 1  3   2
# 4: B 2 1  3   1
# 5: B 1 0  3   2
```

And it could have been written in two lines instead of one:

```
DT[,nx:=.N,by=X]
DT[,nxy:=.N,by=list(X,Y)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# Assuming your data frame is called df:
df$Fx <- ave(as.numeric(as.factor(df$X)), df$X, FUN = length)
df2 <- as.data.frame(with(df, table(X, Y)), responseName = "Fyx")
df3 <- merge(df, df2)
# please see @thelatemail's clean `ave`-only calculation of 'Fyx'

df3

#   X Y Z Fx Fyx
# 1 A 1 0  2   1
# 2 A 2 1  2   1
# 3 B 1 1  3   2
# 4 B 1 0  3   2
# 5 B 2 1  3   1


# And a ddply alternative
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(.data = df, .variables = .(X), mutate,
  Fx = length(X))

ddply(.data = df2, .variables = .(X, Y), mutate,
  Fxy = length(Y))
```

Comment: Just so you know, `ave` can take multiple arguments for the grouping variables to avoid needing to do the merge etc. It would nearly be identical to the `ddply` solution.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks for the suggestion, and +1 to your nice `ave` solution! `'ave` a good night!

Answer (score 3):

Using `ave` and assuming your data is `dat`

```
dat$Fx <-  with(dat,ave(Y,list(X),FUN=length))
dat$Fyx <- with(dat,ave(Y,list(X,Y),FUN=length))
```

Result:

```
  X Y Z Fx Fyx
1 A 1 0  2   1
2 A 2 1  2   1
3 B 1 1  3   2
4 B 2 1  3   1
5 B 1 0  3   2
```

If the data doesn't have a numeric column for `ave` to work on, then:

```
dat$Fx <-  with(dat,ave(seq_len(nrow(dat)),list(X),FUN=length))
dat$Fyx <- with(dat,ave(seq_len(nrow(dat)),list(X,Y),FUN=length))
```