# Add a column for counting unique tuples in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
userID <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5)
A      <- c(2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1)
B      <- c(2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df     <- data.frame(userID, A, B)
df
#   userID A B
# 1      1 2 2
# 2      1 3 3
# 3      3 2 1
# 4      5 1 0
# 5      3 2 1
# 6      5 1 0
```

I would like to create a data frame with the same columns but with an added final column that counts up the number of unique tuples / combinations of the other columns. The output should look like the following:

```
userID A B count
     1 2 2     1
     1 3 3     1
     3 2 1     2 
     5 1 0     2
```

The meaning is the the tuple / combination of (1, 2, 2) occurs with count=1, while the tuple of (3, 2, 1) occurs twice so has count=2. I would prefer **not** to use any external packages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860355/how-to-get-frequencies-then-add-it-as-a-variable-in-an-array/

Comment: NO! That question does not ask for counts of tuples. It only asks for counts of single columns. Learn to read.

Comment: Being rude doesn't inspire people to help you.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, if *you* read the linked question completely, you would see that it asks for counts of single columns ***and*** for the counts of tuples. The only thing left would be dropping the duplicated rows that were found.

Comment: The fact that my question has been answered by so many people proves that my question is ELITE and UNIQUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) aggregate**

```
ag <- aggregate(count ~ ., cbind(count = 1, df), length)
ag[do.call("order", ag), ]  # sort the rows
```

giving:

```
  userID A B count
3      1 2 2     1
4      1 3 3     1
2      3 2 1     2
1      5 1 0     2
```

The last line of code which sorts the rows could be omitted if the order of the rows is unimportant.

The remaining solutions use the indicated packages:

**2) sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
Names <- toString(names(df))
fn$sqldf("select *, count(*) count from df group by $Names order by $Names")
```

giving:

```
  userID A B count
1      1 2 2     1
2      1 3 3     1
3      3 2 1     2
4      5 1 0     2
```

The order by clause could be omitted if the order is unimportant.

**3) dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% regroup(as.list(names(df))) %>% summarise(count = n())
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: userID, A
  userID A B count
1      1 2 2     1
2      1 3 3     1
3      3 2 1     2
4      5 1 0     2
```

**4) data.table**

```
library(data.table)
data.table(df)[, list(count = .N), by = names(df)]
```

giving:

```
   userID A B count
1:      1 2 2     1
2:      1 3 3     1
3:      3 2 1     2
4:      5 1 0     2
```

*ADDED* additional solutions.  Also some small improvements.

Comment: With respect to the dplyr way:  
"'regroup' is deprecated.
Use 'group_by_' instead."

Comment: Also, "%.% is deprecated. Please use %>% "

Comment: what about updating `regroup`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly straightforward way (`ave` to the rescue!):

```
unique(cbind(df, 
             count = ave(rep(1, nrow(df)),
                         do.call(paste, df), 
                         FUN = length)))
#   userID A B count
# 1      1 2 2     1
# 2      1 3 3     1
# 3      3 2 1     2
# 4      5 1 0     2
```

---

Here's a variation of the above:

```
unique(within(df, {
  counter <- rep(1, nrow(df))
  count <- ave(counter, df, FUN = length)
  rm(counter)
}))
#   userID A B count
# 1      1 2 2     1
# 2      1 3 3     1
# 3      3 2 1     2
# 4      5 1 0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userID <- c(1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 5)
A      <- c(2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1)
B      <- c(2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df     <- data.frame(userID, A, B)
```

Make a quick factor of the tuples:

```
df$AB <- as.factor(paste(df$userID,df$A,df$B, sep=""))
```

No external packages just taking advantage of summary() and storing it as a DF then merging the counts on the original data:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(summary(df$AB))
df2 <- data.frame(x=row.names(df2), y=df2[1])
names(df2) <- c("AB", "count")
df <- merge(df, df2, by="AB", all.x=TRUE)
df$AB <- NULL
```

Almost final output, just has dupes:

```
df

  userID A B count
1      1 2 2     1
2      1 3 3     1
3      3 2 1     2
4      3 2 1     2
5      5 1 0     2
6      5 1 0     2
```

Lastly, clean up dupes:

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

Here you go:

```
df

  userID A B count
1      1 2 2     1
2      1 3 3     1
3      3 2 1     2
5      5 1 0     2
```

Been a while not doing that with sql or plyr. if you can use dplyr or a package later on do it. Bioconductor has a lot of great sequencing packages if it starts to get more complex.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, even if it is a little bit ugly:

```
vec <- table(apply(df,1,paste,collapse=""))

df2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(names(vec),"")))

names(df2) <- names(df)
df2$count <- vec

#  userID A B count
#1      1 2 2     1
#2      1 3 3     1
#3      3 2 1     2
#4      5 1 0     2
```